# how to pass the dynamic filename in csv data set config in jmeter while the dynamic names are generated to save data of previous request?

Tags: jmeter

I have one http request whose response comes in nested json and using groovy i am saving that data in different csv file on the basis of conditions.
the name of csv file is generated dynamically and saved in a variable
using vars.put() function
vars.put("_cFileName",cFileName.toString());

when try to use this variable in csv data set config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y833P.png)

getting error message
2022-01-19 16:58:39,370 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File ${_cFileName} must exist and be readable

it is not converting the name to actual file name

But in case if file name is not dynaamic and the variable is defined under user defined variable in test plan it will able to convert to actual file name?

is there any way we can use the dynamic name created in an previos request post processor?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, as per [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) Configuration Elements are executed before everything else, CSV Data Set Config is a [Configuration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) hence it's being initialized before any [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are being set.

The solution would be moving to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead), JMeter Functions are evaluated at the time they're being called so it's possible to provide dynamic file name there, see [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) guide for more details if needed.